# DataTables Searching Option is not working

Tags: datatable

If i search "Hossain" datatable is not getting sorted. Though this data is available in datatable. How can i solve this problem?

```
      var table = $('#list_table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "destroy":    true,
        "searching":  true,
        "ordering":   true,
        "bInfo":   true,
        "paging": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{URL::to('/')}}/current_employeelist",
            "type": "POST",
            "headers":{'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},  
            "data":   {location: $("#location").val()}                
        },
        "columns": [
            {
              "render": function (data, type, JsonResultRow, meta) {
                return '<img src="{{asset('employee_image')}}/'+JsonResultRow.Images+'" style="height:30px; width:30px; border-radius: 30px;"/>';
              }
            },                
          { "data": "Link",
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<a target="_blank"  href="{{URL::to('/')}}/employeeinfo/'+full.id+'">'+full.employee_name+'</a>';
            }
          },
          { "data": "location_name" },                     
          { "data": "depertment_name" },                     
          { "data": "designation_name" },                     
          { "data": "contact_number" },                     
          { "data": "joining_date" },  
          @permission('EditEmployeeInfo')          
          { "data": "Link", name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
          @endpermission
        ],[enter image description here][1]
        "order": [[0, 'asc']]
      });
```

I want to get searching actual data from datatable.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCMD3.png)